# retrieving access token reddit API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, reddit

I am looking at the reddit api and following the guidelines to get an `access_token` - [see here](https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/OAuth2#retrieving-the-access-token).

The code I have is as follows:

```
componentDidMount() {

  const code = '12345';
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + (CLIENT_ID + ":" + CLIENT_SECRET));

    fetch('https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token', {
      method: 'post',
      headers,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        code,
        redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000'
      })
    });
  }
}
```

This is returning a `401` error,  and if I remove the headers it gets stuck on a `200 OPTIONS`.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?